# I can not updated my ubuntu 12.04 Failed to fetch 403 "Two Host Req Hdr"

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager

I have a problem these days, I can not update system. Every time I try `sudo apt-get update` the answer is:

```
Failed to fetch 
403 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources
Two Host Req Hdr [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
```

like where to fix it?...

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem yesterday, at first time I thought that's because the repository, so I changed that but it still like that
Then I've found that 403 means the request was legal but the server refuse to respond it
So I try to changed the dns into the google's dns, and apt-get works fine like usually.

Note : I am using wifi from android gadget, and I changed the dns in my gadget, not in my laptop.

Sorry for my english language.
Hope can help.